# sequence on pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create sequence MYSEQ_sequence
start with 100
increment by 5;
```

I just created the sequence in sql. I want to create pl/sql anonymous block program unit that shows the curval, and nextval of the sequence MYSEQ. Does anybody know how to put it in pl/sql?

Answer (score 3):

A simple query will do:

```
SELECT MYSEQ_sequence.currval, MYSEQ_sequence.nextval
FROM DUAL
```

You don't even need a PL/SQL block for this.

Comment: Sorry, It should display that PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. Current value : 100, Next Value : 105 as text.

Comment: It showed that ERROR at line 4: 
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Hi,
 You can use below procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_name (sequence_name varchar2)
AS
V_NEXTVAL integer;
V_SELECT varchar2(100);
BEGIN
V_SELECT := 'SELECT'||sequence_name||'.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
EXECUTE IMMMEDIATE V_SELECT INTO V_NEXTVAL; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('Nextval is: '||TO_CHAR(V_NEXTVAL));
END;
```

Comment: I did not learn the pl/sql yet, but just trying to learn it in advance.

Comment: Understand, but post you code, how you are applying logic?

Comment: I even don't have a code yet. I need to look at the book now. Thank you very much for your help sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MYSEQ_sequence
MINVALUE 100
START WITH 100
INCREMENT BY 5;

SELECT MYSEQ_sequence.currval AS seq
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tested this one and it works:

```
DECLARE
   V_CUR    VARCHAR2 (32);
   V_NEXT   VARCHAR2 (32);
BEGIN
   SELECT MYSEQ_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL
     INTO V_CUR
     FROM DUAL;
   SELECT MYSEQ_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL
     INTO V_NEXT
     FROM DUAL;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_CUR);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_NEXT);
END;
```

IMPORTANT:
-You have to get the first value of this sequence once.
-If you get both values in a single try, you'll get one number

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
    curr NUMBER;
    nxt NUMBER; 
BEGIN
    SELECT MYSEQ_sequence.currval, MYSEQ_sequence.nextval
    INTO curr, nxt
    FROM DUAL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Current value: ' || curr || ' ' || 'Next value: ' || nxt);
END;
```